# How to save results of a promise to a variable and transfer it to another function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I make calendar for my project and need to use seved data from server inside "function CalendarPicker()".
I get data from server as promise and try use it inside "function CalendarPicker()" but always get undefined. How can I force it?

```
async function _getMeetingsData() {
    let response = await fetch('calendar');
    let data = await response.json();
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    return data;
}

function CalendarPicker() {
    //Get meeting data
    this.meetingsData = _getMeetingsData();

    this._insertNavigationButtons();
    this._insertHeaderIntoCalendarWrapper();
    this._insertCalendarGridDaysHeader();
    this._insertDaysIntoGrid();
    this._insertCalendarIntoWrapper();
}

const myCalender = new CalendarPicker();
```

Comment: Anything that uses `this.meetingsData` needs to be async as well so it can await `_getMeetingsData`.

Comment: It's probably better to make an async factory that returns a fully initialized CalendarPicker. You can't `await new`, so if you don't do this, you will create a new CalendarPicker, but then you can't use until its' ready, and there's nothing to await.

Comment: Thank U for answer man, I tried to call _getMeetingsData with the await and I always get the error. But you provide me really useful article! Thank U!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an `async` constructor (arguably odd) or `await` for your data, because every `async` function is implicitly a *promise*, even if it synchronously returns a value ... so:

```
function CalendarPicker() {
  //Get meeting data ... then
  _getMeetingsData().then(meetingsData => {
    this.meetingsData = meetingsData;
    this._insertNavigationButtons();
    this._insertHeaderIntoCalendarWrapper();
    this._insertCalendarGridDaysHeader();
    this._insertDaysIntoGrid();
    this._insertCalendarIntoWrapper();
  });
}
```

This works, but if you have any prototype method that needs that data, you better store the promise:

```
function CalendarPicker() {
  //Get meeting data ... then
  this._meetingsData = _getMeetingsData().then(meetingsData => {
    this.meetingsData = meetingsData;
    this._insertNavigationButtons();
    this._insertHeaderIntoCalendarWrapper();
    this._insertCalendarGridDaysHeader();
    this._insertDaysIntoGrid();
    this._insertCalendarIntoWrapper();
  });
}

CalendarPicker.prototype.doThings = function () {
  this._meetingsData.then(() => {
    console.log(this.meetingsData);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined `_getMeetingsData` as an `async` function, you need to call `_getMeetingsData` with the `await` keyword. In that case, you also need to make `CalendarPicker` an `async` function. Alternatively, you can call `_getMeetingsData` within a **promise** construct in your `CalendarPicker` function.

Comment: Thank U for answer man, I tried to call _getMeetingsData with the await and I always get the error.

Comment: Did you make CalendarPicker async?

Comment: Yes, I making it right now.